# MySQL Retrieve Records Where Criteria is Unique and True i.e. No other records exist

Tags: mysql, subquery, criteria, unique

I have a legacy database that I am working with a basic column layout as such:

```
SampleID
CompanyID
CompanyApplication
CompanyTest1
...
CompanyTest25
```

Not normalized in the least, this is causing a bit of a data mining issue.

I need to get the CompanyIDs (Grouped By) where the CompanyApplication field = "Registration" but this company has none of the CompanyTest(n) fields selected for any SampleID.

The problem is, there are CompanyIDs that have both CompanyApplication and CompanyTest(n) records (multiple rows), but I want to get CompanyIDs that only have a CompanyApplication of Registration.

Data to help illustrate:

```
SampleID | CompanyID | CompanyApplication | CompanyTest1 | ... | CompanyTest25
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 1        | Registration       |              |     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         | 1        |                    | True         |     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
3         | 2        | Registration       |              |     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
4         | 2        | Registration       |              |     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
5         | 3        |                    | True         |     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
6         | 3        |                    |              |     | True
```

I only want to retrieve rows 3 and 4 because they ONLY have Registration and no other testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could start by selecting all of the rows that you are trying to exclude, and then use a `NOT EXISTS` to skip over `CompanyID`s that are in that query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ct1.company_id
FROM company_table AS ct1
WHERE ct1.CompanyApplication = "Registration"
  AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM company_table AS ct2
        WHERE ct1.company_id = ct2.compnay_id
          AND (ct2.CompanyTest1 IS NOT NULL
               OR ct2.CompanyTest2 IS NOT NULL
               ...
               OR ct2.CompanyTest25 IS NOT NULL)
        )
```

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that I don't want to do ct2.CompanyTest1 IS NOT NULL
OR ct2.CompanyTest2 IS NOT NULL
...
OR ct2.CompanyTest25 IS NOT NULL
Because that is a lot of typing and I'm wondering if there is a more slick way to do it.

Comment: probably there is not away around that;  as a rule, sql treats distinct columns as totally different data, which can't trivially be combined in a way that would let you use them as a collection.  If they should have been a collection, then they belong in the same column;  This is the downside of leaving a legacy schema in place, instead of migrating it to a closer representation of what it actually means.

Comment: Believe me I want to fix this schema, but extracting data needs to happen now and rewriting this schema (and the 64 other tables involved in this database) is taking a considerable time commitment. Thank you for the code. I Always forget about EXISTS